# How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, dockerhub

I have been trying to set up a container for a development postgres instance by creating a custom user & database. I am using the [official postgres docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). In the documentation it instructs you to insert a bash script inside of the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder to set up the database with any custom parameters.

### My bash script: make_db.sh

```
su postgres -c "createuser -w -d -r -s docker"
su postgres -c "createdb -O docker docker"
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM library/postgres

RUN ["mkdir", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"]
ADD make_db.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The error I get from the `docker logs -f db` (db is my container name) is:

> createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

It seems that the commands inside of the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder are being executed before postgres is started. My question is, how do I set up a user/database programmatically using the official postgres container? Is there any way to do this with a script?

Answer (score 629, accepted):

### EDIT - since Jul 23, 2015

The [official postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) will run `.sql` scripts found in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder.

So all you need is to create the following sql script:

*init.sql*

```
CREATE USER docker;
CREATE DATABASE docker;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
```

and add it in your Dockerfile:

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM library/postgres
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

---

But since July 8th, 2015, **if all you need is to create a user and database**, it is easier to just make use to the `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRES_DB` environment variables:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -e POSTGRES_DB=docker library/postgres
```

or with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM library/postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER docker
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD docker
ENV POSTGRES_DB docker
```

---

### for images older than Jul 23, 2015

From [the documentation of the postgres Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), it is said that

> [...] it will source any *.sh script found in that directory [`/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`] to do further initialization before starting the service

What's important here is *"before starting the service"*. This means your script *make_db.sh* will be executed before the postgres service would be started, hence the error message *"could not connect to database postgres"*.

After that there is another useful piece of information:

> If you need to execute SQL commands as part of your initialization, the use of Postgres single user mode is highly recommended.

Agreed this can be a bit mysterious at the first look. What it says is that your initialization script should start the postgres service in single mode before doing its actions. So you could change your *make_db.ksh* script as follows and it should get you closer to what you want:

**NOTE**, this has changed recently [in the following commit](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/75/commits).  This will work with the latest change:

```sh
export PGUSER=postgres
psql <<- EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
EOSQL
```

Previously, the use of `--single` mode was required:

```sh
gosu postgres postgres --single <<- EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
EOSQL
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. I guess I just didn't understand the purpose of single user mode before. Interesting feature!

Comment: Is there a way to run an sql file in single user mode

Comment: you can with: `gosu postgres postgres --single < /tmp/somefile.sql`

Comment: How can I run `psql -U myDb -d myDb -f myDb.sql`

Comment: Note, --single is no longer supported in any of the postgres Dockerfiles.

Comment: I followed the steps and when I ssh into the mysql container and cd into `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` I see my `init.sql` with the sql code in it. BUT when I open mysql (using root access) and type show databases I see only the default on from the `docker-compose.yml` file! Why it's not working for me?

Comment: inside the Dockerfile, you can prevent creating multiple cache layers by chaining all of the `ENV` commands together, like `ENV POSTGRES_USER=docker POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker POSTGRES_DB=docker`

Comment: Using the `ENV` variables creates a superuser of the database (like the default `postgres` superuser). I want to create a user for my service which is not a superuser, using the script works, but how do I set the user's password?

Comment: try `CREATE USER "$POSTGRES_USER" PASSWORD $pass ;` See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-createuser.html

Comment: Its not executing `db.sql` even after it is copied to `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d\`

Comment: Simple note to otherwise very valuable and helpful answer: On Windows, I had troubles with the .sh script in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. *The script must not contain `\r` character.* I made it working after concatenating commands using `;` character. (In my case the script was not too long - only mvn calls to initialize db via flyway.)

Comment: Just to add to this. `.sh` scripts also run when put under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Comment: What if there are more than 1 file in `docker-entrypoint.initdb.d`?

Comment: @kamal, they all get loaded, see the entrypoint script: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/3f585c58df93e93b730c09a13e8904b96fa20c58/11/docker-entrypoint.sh#L132

Comment: Does this cause the database to be deleted between deployments? I find that my db is blown away every time I scale to zero then back to n pods.

Comment: How do I execute multiple SQL files present in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder in a specific sequence?

Comment: files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` are taken in alphabetical order. Just prefix your file names with numbers : `001-create-tables.sql`, `002-insert-data.sql`; ...

Comment: Won't this try to re-create existing databases and objects every time the service is launched --and work only the first time? Also, what about trying to do this when you're using `docker secrets` with `docker-compose`?

Comment: no, only when the volume holding Postgres data is empty.

Comment: Although this is marked as the correct answer, there is a nuance here nobody talked about: POSTGRES_USER/PASSWORD will set the _super user_ in your database. That may not always be a good idea to use for your main database user. Instead consider creating a separate _application_ user & database.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm still getting the error "psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Comment: As per September 2021, this can be seen on PostgreSQL official page on docker:

**Warning**: scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` are only run if you start the container with a data directory _that is empty_.

Comment: @LucasBr exactly! I'm having issues with the Postgres image not recreating the user specified by the env vars in a production environment that uses a persistent volume.
For persistent here I mean that every time I restart the container, I don't wipe out the volumes but instead I just do a down and then an up -d.

And this is written basically nowhere

Comment: How do you get these to execute as PSQL though? Instead of only SQL? Similarly, doesn't this blow away the DB every time you restart the container...?

Answer (score 58):

By using `docker-compose`:

Assuming that you have following directory layout:

```
$MYAPP_ROOT/docker-compose.yml
           /Docker/init.sql
           /Docker/db.Dockerfile
```

File: `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: ./Docker
      dockerfile: db.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./var/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

File: `Docker/init.sql`

```sql
CREATE USER myUser;

CREATE DATABASE myApp_dev;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myApp_dev TO myUser;

CREATE DATABASE myApp_test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myApp_test TO myUser;
```

File: `Docker/db.Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:11.5-alpine
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Composing and starting services:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --no-start
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml start
```

Answer (score 41):

With docker compose there's a simple alternative (no need to create a Dockerfile). Just create a init-database.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE my_project_development;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_project_development TO docker;
    CREATE DATABASE my_project_test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_project_test TO docker;
EOSQL
```

And reference it in the volumes section:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres:
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It appears the volumes directive creates a directory, not a file, in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. The errors is that the file is a directory.

Comment: Confirmed it works perfect on my local machine. Just one thing we need to make local `./init-database.sh` executable by running `chmod 755 ./init-datbase.sh`.

Comment: docker creates an empty directory if the source file is not found...
for me that means usually i messed up the paths...

Comment: Sorry, bit of a noob question - in docker-compose you specify `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` for the container environment. Why is this not used in `init-database.sh` (whilst `POSTGRES_USER` is)?

Comment: where do you put chmod 755 inside the docker-compose file?

Answer (score 26):

You can use this commands:

```
docker exec -it yournamecontainer psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE mydatabase ENCODING 'LATIN1' TEMPLATE template0 LC_COLLATE 'C' LC_CTYPE 'C';"

docker exec -it yournamecontainer psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE postgres TO postgres;"
```

Comment: `ENCODING 'LATIN1'` is very weird... You must have very particular needs to avoid using utf8

Answer (score 17):

You can now put .sql files inside the init directory:

[From the docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres)

> If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (creating the directory if necessary). After the entrypoint calls initdb to create the default postgres user and database, it will run any *.sql files and source any *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.

So copying your .sql file in will work.

Comment: environmental variables for user/password and db creation still works. (9.5.3)

Comment: I have a project that works locally. However, when I move it to AWS EC2, it says that DB is not found. I copy the .sql file in the proper directory, but it still returns that error. Any idea where I could look? I am new to Docker.

Comment: This is only true if there is a single db instance bound to a single volume, i.e. it won't run any scripts if anything is already in the volume folder. This gives me a headache, because I want to have a separate db initializers for each of my stack services.

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#initialization-scripts) 

`Warning: scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup. One common problem is that if one of your /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and your orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized data directory, it will not continue on with your scripts.`

Comment: What is the order in which sql files are applied in case we have multiple?

Answer (score 10):

With Postgres latest image (ID: b262c8b2fb54) and Docker version 20.10.6 the docker-compose will look like,

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    # the detail of app
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    container_name: book-shop-db-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=bookshop-db
```

This will create the user, databases as mentioned while starting

Answer (score 10):

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
   postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ${PROJECTDIR}/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

Here are two things you need to consider:

1. `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will only work when your data dictionary is empty. So if you have volumes, be sure to delete them `docker-compose down --volumes`.
2. Create your user and database in the `init.sql` instead of  `docke-compose.yml`. In `docker-compose.yml`, you should specify the `postgres` user .

Answer (score 8):

I add custom commands to a environment evoked in a CMD after starting services... I haven't done it with postgres, but with Oracle:

```
#set up var with noop command
RUN export POST_START_CMDS=":"
RUN mkdir /scripts
ADD script.sql /scripts
CMD service oracle-xe start; $POST_START_CMDS; tail -f /var/log/dmesg
```

and start with

```
docker run -d ... -e POST_START_CMDS="su - oracle -c 'sqlplus @/scripts/script' " <image>
```

.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the database running before you create the users.  For this you need multiple processes.  You can either start postgres in a subshell (&) in the shell script, or use a tool like supervisord to run postgres and then run any initialization scripts.

A guide to supervisord and docker https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: Or just `RUN service postgresql start ; su - postgres -c "psql -c \"CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test' CREATEDB\"" ; service postgresql stop`

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the previous answers, I had a dump from a database named `ecomm-db.sql` where `ecomm-db` is the actual database name that I wanted to import to a local docker container.

The `ecomm-db.sql` file already had a user named `admin` that it was referencing, with statements such as `ALTER TABLE public."Products" OWNER TO admin;`

The way I could get it all to work is:

- Create the user `admin` and database `ecomm-db` using (using `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_DB` respectively in docker compose)
- Create a script `role.sh` that grants all privileges on the newly created `ecomm-db` to the user `admin`
- Initialize the container with the `role.sh` script and the `ecomm-db.sql` file.

There is no need to create a new `Dockerfile`

- `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - postgres-net
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=ecomm-db
    volumes:
      - postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init/role.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/role.sh # order matters
      - ./init/ecomm-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql # name in container is arbitrary
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
```

- `init/role.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ecomm-db TO admin;
EOSQL
```

- `init/ecomm-db.sh` (snippet)

```sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg20.04+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg20.04+1)

...

ALTER TABLE public."Products" OWNER TO admin;
...
```