# How to set PostgreSQL schema for Keycloak when using the Docker Image?

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

i am trying to use the Docker Image for Keycloak but I seem to be unable to set a schema for the tables that are created in PostgreSQL.

Currently all tables end up in the public schema. Is there a way that i can instruct Keycloak to create the tables inside a schema?

Comment: I have tried setting currentSchema=keycloak as a JDBC parameter on the connection url and it still uses public. I am not sure if this is possible. According to what I have read currentSchema will only affect unqualified sql statements. So if public.table name is referenced it will use that any way.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Use `DB_SCHEMA` env variable taking care of creating the schema before running keycloak.

### More details

The docker image of keycloak supports the `DB_SCHEMA` environment variable.
However the schema must created before you run keycloak.

Here's an example of a docker compose that would first create the schema in the postgres container and then run keycloak.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /c/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # This will bind the files inside the pgscripts to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      # The scripts will be run on startup
      - $PWD/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      # This is required otherwise the container will fail to start
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      DB_VENDOR: postgres
      DB_ADDR: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_SCHEMA: keycloak_schema
      DB_DATABASE: postgres
      DB_USER: keycloak_user
      DB_PASSWORD: keycloak_password
```

Notice that I'm using volume binding to bind the files under the host `postgres` directory to the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (more info here: [How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres))

Here's the init.sql script

```
CREATE USER keycloak_user WITH PASSWORD 'keycloak_password';
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS keycloak_schema AUTHORIZATION keycloak_user;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This works for both the legacy WildFly release as well as the Quarkus release.

Answer (score 2):

Find **all possible config parameters** at
https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Direct link to **the ones for the database connection**
https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config#_database

For example the **current schema param** is

- CLI: --db-schema
- Env: KC_DB_SCHEMA

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the `POSTGRES_DATABASE` env variable for the data source:

`docker ... -e POSTGRES_DATABASE=<your_database_name> ...`

By default, it should be using the database name `'keycloak'`, so it's weird you don't see that:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=KeycloakDS: add(jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS,enabled=true,use-java-context=true,use-ccm=true, connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://${env.POSTGRES_ADDR:postgres}:${env.POSTGRES_PORT:5432}/${env.POSTGRES_DATABASE:keycloak}, driver-name=postgresql)
```

source code:
https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/cd866b905d026eb69dab5176b352064252d92aff/server/cli/databases/postgres/change-database.cli#L2

**Update**

Sorry, I see what you mean.  In that case, I think you'll have to manually create the schema in the database, then update the `standalone.xml` to use your schema:

```
<spi name="connectionsJpa">
  <provider name="default" enabled="true">
    <properties>
      <property name="dataSource" value="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"/>
      <property name="initializeEmpty" value="true"/>
      <property name="migrationStrategy" value="update"/>
      <property name="migrationExport" value="${jboss.home.dir}/keycloak-database-update.sql"/>
      <property name="schema" value="your_schema"/>
    </properties>
  </provider>
</spi>
```

It looks like they [don't support automatic schema creation](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1351), so you'll probably have to submit a feature request.

Comment: Hi Tom, the database is not a problem but i was wondering if it possible to set a schema within that database. Currently the tables are correctly created but in the public schema of a database.

Comment: If the solution of using a customized `standalone.xml` works for you, you can consider adding it in the docker image directly.