# Kubernetes, spring boot and microservices

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I'm developing a microservices application with Spring Boot and Postgres. Using Docker, the REST API in one container and Postgres in another container, everything works fine. But when I try to run this with Kubernetes , it always gives an API error.

The `Dockerfile` where my Spring Boot-based API is defined looks as follows:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add openjdk8
MAINTAINER rjdesenvolvimento.com
COPY target/apipessoas-0.0.1.jar /opt/gaia/apipessoas.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/opt/gaia/apipessoas.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

The `Dockerfile` for Postgres:

```
FROM postgres:10-alpine
MAINTAINER rjdesenvolvimento.com
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432
CMD ["postgres"]
ADD postgres.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
EXPOSE 5432
```

My `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  postgres:
    build:
      dockerfile: postgres.dockerfile
      context: .
    image: rjdesenvolvimento/postgres-apipessoas
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /home/rodrigo/Projetos/Volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - gaia_network

  apipessoas:
    build:
      dockerfile: api-pessoa.dockerfile
      context: .
    image: rjdesenvolvimento/api-pessoas
    container_name: api_pessoas
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - gaia_network
networks:
  gaia_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now, my Kubernetes Postgres mainfest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    name: postgres-api-pessoas
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: postgres
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres-api-pessoas
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container-postgres-api-pessoas
        image: rjdesenvolvimento/postgres-apipessoas
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
         - name: POSTGRES0_USER
           value: postgres
         - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
           value: postgres
         - name: POSTGRES_DB
           value: zeus
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432          
          name: zeus
        volumeMounts:
          - name: volume-postgres-api-pessoas
            mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: volume-postgres-api-pessoas
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

And the API manifest:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: servico-api-pessoas
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: api-pessoas-pod
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-api-pessoas
  labels:
    app: api-pessoas-pod
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-pessoas-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-pessoas-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: contaienr-api-pessoas
        image: rjdesenvolvimento/api-pessoas
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

When I deploy above YAML manifest to Kubernetes I get this error:

```
deployment-api-pessoas-8cfd5c6c5-dpln4   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
postgres-api-pessoas-0                   1/1       Running            0          28m
```

What im doing wrong?

ADD:

describe pod

```
Name:           deployment-api-pessoas-8cfd5c6c5-nhtff
Namespace:      default
Node:           minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:     Sun, 16 Sep 2018 11:19:02 -0400
Labels:         app=api-pessoas-pod
                pod-template-hash=479817271
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.5
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/deployment-api-pessoas-8cfd5c6c5
Containers:
  contaienr-api-pessoas:
    Container ID:   docker://a6fb9a254895bb31effdcadd66675cfb5197f72d526f805d20cbbde90c0677cc
    Image:          rjdesenvolvimento/api-pessoas
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:f326d42c0afd7b4f3d3e7a06e8a2625f7a841a7451a08c2b326e90e13459b244
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 16 Sep 2018 11:19:48 -0400
      Finished:     Sun, 16 Sep 2018 11:20:02 -0400
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sun, 16 Sep 2018 11:19:11 -0400
      Finished:     Sun, 16 Sep 2018 11:19:42 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-x9s8k (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          False 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  default-token-x9s8k:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-x9s8k
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned deployment-api-pessoas-8cfd5c6c5-nhtff to minikube
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                 kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-x9s8k"
  Normal   Pulled                 26s (x2 over 1m)   kubelet, minikube  Container image "rjdesenvolvimento/api-pessoas" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                23s (x2 over 1m)   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started                21s (x2 over 58s)  kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                6s                 kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
```

the log is too big, but I think I found the problem:

```
     attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'pessoaJuridicaFuncionarioResource' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/opt/gaia/apipessoas.jar!/BOOT-
INF/classes!/com/rjdesenvolvimento/apipessoas/resource/funcionario/PessoaJ
uridicaFuncionarioResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'pessoaJuridicaFuncionarioService' defined in URL 
[jar:file:/opt/gaia/apipessoas.jar!/BOOT-
INF/classes!/com/rjdesenvolvimento/apipessoas/service/funcionario/PessoaJu
ridicaFuncionarioService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
constructor parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name 'pessoaJuridicaFuncionarioRepository': Cannot create inner 
bean '(inner bean)#37ddb69a' of type 
[org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting 
bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
bean with name '(inner bean)#37ddb69a': Cannot resolve reference to bean 
'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of 
FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: 
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL 
[jar:file:/opt/gaia/apipessoas.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/data.sql]: INSERT 
INTO zeus.endereco.pais (nome) VALUES ('Brasil'); nested exception is 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "endereco.pais" does 
not exist
Position: 13
```

HIBERNATE can not create any table.

```
Hibernate: 

    create table endereco.endereco_pessoa_fisica_funcionario (
       id  bigserial not null,
        bairro varchar(255) not null,
        cep varchar(255) not null,
        complemento varchar(255) not null,
        logradouro varchar(255) not null,
        numero varchar(255) not null,
        fk_cidade int8,
        fk_pessoafisicafuncionario int8,
        primary key (id)
    )
2018-09-16 15:27:03.480  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.rjdesenvolvimento.apipessoas.ApipessoasApplication.main(ApipessoasApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[apipessoas.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[apipessoas.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[apipessoas.jar:0.0.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[apipessoas.jar:0.0.1]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "endereco" does not exist
  Position: 19
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266) ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar!/:42.2.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 42 common frames omitted


but if i run with docker-compose without kubertes, everthing works ok
```

ADD:

in my application.properties:

1) if i run in my pc withou docker:
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://locahost:port/db_name

2) if i run in docker
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://docker_db_container_name:port/db_name

Now I do not know how to make the api rest "see" the database with kubernetes

ADD:

First I wanted to apologize for my absence.
I had personal problems.
Secondly, I would like to thank you all for your help so far.

I modified my Kubernetes files:

postgres

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
    camada: banco-de-dados
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: zeus
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: lk85Kab5aCn904Ad
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume
  labels:
    app: postgres
    tipo: local
spec:
  capacity: 
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /home/rodrigo/Projetos/VolumeKube
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: rjdesenvolvimento/postgres-apipessoas
        imagePullPolicy: Never 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: postgres-config
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
            name: postgres-database
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-database
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-volume-claim
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
  - port: 5432
```

and API

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-pessoas
  labels:
    app: api-pessoas
    camada: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-pessoas
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-pessoas
        camada: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-pessoas
        image: rjdesenvolvimento/api-pessoas
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api-pessoas
  labels:
    app: api-pessoas
    camada: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: api-pessoas
    camada: backend
  ports:
  - port: 8080
```

The error continued. So I read quietly and realized that kubernetes created "zeus DB" but did not create the SCHEMAS.

when I create my Docker image, from DockerFile, I add the following file:

```
CREATE DATABASE zeus;
\connect zeus;
CREATE SCHEMA funcionario;
CREATE SCHEMA endereco;
CREATE SCHEMA tabela_auxiliar;
CREATE SCHEMA cliente;
```

But this information is not passed on to Kubernetes. So I have to manually enter and add them. And then everything works.

How do I make the information automatically added?

Comment: Try describing your pod to see why the `CrashLoopBackOff` is happening. Something like `kubectl describe pods deployment-api.....`. What does it say?

Comment: Urosh is in the right ballpark, but I would value seeing `kubectl logs deployment-api-pessoas-8cfd5c6c5-dpln4` much more than `describe`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel sometimes the logs don't show any errors that are catched with describe. Both outputs should be added to the question.

Comment: Definitely should get the pod error. Probably pod is failing to connect to postgres Service. If so the log will help determine why. If the Pod's internal config for finding Service looks right (including the hostname or jdbcUrl) then might have to debug the Service - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-have-any-endpoints

Comment: Thanks all for replay. 
I edited the question by adding the LOG and DESCRIBE.

Comment: Could you check the DNS resolution for your headless service like described here?: 
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-a-headless-service-in-Kubernetes
Could you run interactive postgresql client and check the ability to create tables using the same account as in your application image?:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/postgresql-docker/blob/master/9/README.md#postgres-cli

Comment: Take a look at [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) concept in Kubernetes. What you must ideally do is to create a script that will do your tasks of creating DB and schemas and have the script run as part of your Init Container during the Initialization of your API pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how docker compose sets up its internal network, but I can see you are pointing to the same network for both postgres and your service within your docker-compose definition.

As for k8s, you need a way to locate your services as they can be deployed on any node. Either through an internal k8s DNS application or define a Postgres service with a static address (the same way you defined your application service from port 80 to port 8080).

**Solution for API not connected to Postgres**: Create a Postgres service resource. Also get a read at [k8s services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for more help.

**Solution for Postgres not having the expected schemas**: Make sure that your database gets initialized with your user and data by adding the relevant SQL scripts under the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ folder in your Docker image. See a nice answer on how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres).

Comment: Thanks all for replay. I edited the question with new informations

Comment: As VAS suggested, create a headless service: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services then refer to that service in your application.properties

Comment: Another point you must remember is that your Service selector must match the labels of the pods to which you want to expose service. Read            
 [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) example for more details. Additionally run ```kubectl get endpoints``` to see if the service is pointing to Pod_Ip:Port correctly

Comment: Thanks all for replay. I edited the question with new informations

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your issue, your service k8s pod cannot reach the postgres. As you may already know, in k8s, pods are ephemeral and you need services abstraction if you need to invoke a service by its url.

I would ssh into the App pod and try to ping the hostname with which you are trying to connect to the postgres (in your app's config)

```
kubectl exec -it <podname> sh
```

Comment: Thanks all for replay. I edited the question by adding new informations