# Start postgres in Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

When I use the postgres docker image, I run

```
docker run --name mydb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
```

And I see a container running.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
a36b98h8982a        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 minutes ago      Up 36 minutes       5432/tcp                    mydb
```

So I make my Dockerfile because I want to initialize my database

```
FROM postgres:latest

COPY pg-setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

CMD ['postgres']
```

But when I use the Dockerfile the container just exits immediately. How do I get it to run like the postgres image?

Comment: There may be something wrong with the `pg-setup.sql` script. Could you post the logs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your SQL file pg-setup.sql is no problem, you can just change your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM postgres:latest
COPY pg-setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Take a look at another [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres). It will be helpful.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to override the CMD in your dockerfile. The command from the image will be used.

Comment: this doesnt work at all for me: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder335488150/init.sql: no such file or directory