# docker build error: psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

My goal is to create an docker image(postgres) with its default data.

So my plan is to write a dockerfile, use base image `postgres:11`, then copy and run `db0.sql` inside it.

SQL Script: **db0.sql**

```sql
CREATE TABLE "quiz"."example" (
  "name" varchar(255),
  "age" int4,
  "phone" varchar(255),
  "blood_group" varchar(255),
  "height" int4
);

INSERT INTO "quiz"."example" VALUES ('Tony', NULL, NULL, 'O', 180);
ALTER TABLE "quiz"."example" ADD CONSTRAINT "name" UNIQUE ("name");
```

dockerfile: **db0.dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:11
COPY db0.sql /srv/
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start
RUN su postgres
EXPOSE 5432
RUN psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -f /srv/db0.sql
```

But when I run `docker build -t db0 -f db0.dockerfile .`, it shows me the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/6 : FROM postgres:11
 ---> 55ff21ffc6d1
Step 2/6 : COPY db0.sql /srv/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5623b274bfef
Step 3/6 : RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 838cd16f9545
Step 4/6 : RUN su postgres
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c65f67991f0
Step 5/6 : EXPOSE 5432
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a7921ebdf180
Step 6/6 : RUN psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -f /srv/db0.sql
 ---> Running in ddaced269112
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Network is unreachable
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
The command '/bin/sh -c psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -f /srv/db0.sql' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I'm not good at docker, but as I know, the error seems to tell me that

When I try to run `psql` command, but at this time, the postgres service is not ready for use?

---

For now, my final goal is just like do the following command in terminal:

1. `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -v /srv/docker_data/db0:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --name=db0 --restart=always postgres:11`
2. `docker cp db0.sql db0:/srv/`
3. `docker exec -it db0 bash`
4. `su postgres`
5. `psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -f /srv/db0.sql`

After doing these, I can connect into it with a python_team Database, a quiz schema in it with an example table, and a record in it.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres)

dockerfile: **db0.dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres:11

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
COPY db0.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

official postgres image will run *.sql* scripts found inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

and then run `docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -v /srv/docker_data/db0:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres --name=db0 db0`