# Docker Compose - Container Bash Forking

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, netbox

I am trying to run `netbox` based on [their standard guide on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/netboxcommunity/netbox) with a slight difference that I need our existing `postgres` dump to be restored when the `postgres` container starts.

I have tried a few approaches like defining a `command` option in `docker-compose` file like (and a few more combinations):

```sh
sleep 2 && psql -U netbox -f netbox.sql
```

> `sleep` is required to prevent `psql` command running before the `postgres` service is started.

Or defining a bash script that does the database restore but all these approaches cause the container to exit after that command/script is run.

My last resort was to utilize bash forking and this is what the `postgres` snippet of `docker-compose` looks like:

```yaml
postgres:
  image: postgres:13-alpine
  env_file: env/postgres.env
  command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - (sleep 3 && cd /home && psql -U netbox -f netbox.sql) & su -c postgres postgres
  volumes:
    - ./my_db:/home/
    - netbox-postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Sadly this throws results in:

```sh
postgres: could not access the server configuration file
"/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

If I omit the `command` section of `docker-compose`, the container starts up fine and I can navigate and `ls` the directory in the error message but it is not what I really need because this container will go on to be part of a much larger jungle of an ecosystem with little to no control over it afterwards.

Could it be my bash forking or the problem lies somewhere else?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting the dump in the container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, and not trying to manually load it yourself, as in [How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres/26599273#26599273)?

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidMaze, I will give it a shot in the morning. However, from the comments there, it seems not many had success with it. fingers crossed.

Comment: ok, the link you shared led me to solving the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by going through the thread that **David Maze** shared in the comments.

In my case, placing the `*.sql` file inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` did not work but I wrote a `bash` script, placed it in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory and it got triggered.

The `bash` script was a very simple one, it would `cd` to the directory containing the `sql` dump and then restore it by running `psql`:

```sh
psql -U netbox -f netbox.sql
```