# "Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file" on GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions, psql, azure-aks

On the github action I login to Azure CLI and then Connect to the cluster by following commands:

```
az login
az aks get-credentials --resource-group $AKS_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --name $AKS_CLUSTER_NAME
```

[image]

Then I Connect to kubernete pods by following command

```
kubectl exec -it mypod -- //bin/bash
```

If you use the -it flag on the local machine, there should be no problem.
However, when running on Github action, it will have a warning:

```
Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file
```

[image]

Then I Connect to postgres localhost by following command.

```
psql -h  127.0.0.1  -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres
```

I tried removing the -t flag according to some tutorials but it didn't work.
[image]

This means cannot connect to kubernete pods.
In fact, when I connect with my local computer, it succeeds

[image]

Comment: Running with `-it` in a CI environment makes no sense. With `-it`, you're saying you want to have an interactive tty, and you'll be expected to give it some input.

Comment: yes, i need to exetute command psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres after entering pod

Comment: And then what? I mean this psql command just connects you to the database, but you'd still need to enter an SQL query or something. What are you trying to achieve? Run some query?

Comment: After I initialize the DB , I need to create an external user to be able to manipulate the DB.
hence I used command : psql -h  127.0.0.1  -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres and then , i will create an external user

Comment: If you want to run some setup for your database and you're using the official postgres image, perhaps this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26599273/1080523