# How do I run a bash script in a docker container after it starts?

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a bash script after a Postgres container starts which 1) creates a new table within the Postgres DB, and 2) runs a copy command that dumps the contents of a csv file into the newly created table.

Currently, I'm specifying the execution of the script within my `docker-compose.yml` file using the "command" argument, but I find that it doesn't allow the Postgres container to succesfully start. I receive the following information from the log:

```
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I remove the "command" argument everything is fine. Here is what my `docker-compose.yml` files looks like now:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:  # new
      - 8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://fastapi_traefik:fastapi_traefik@db:5432/fastapi_traefik
    depends_on:
      - db
    labels: # new
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.fastapi.rule=Host(`fastapi.localhost`)"
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - "/Users/theComputerPerson/:/tmp"
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_traefik
    command: /bin/bash -c "/tmp/newtable.sh"
  traefik: # new
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      - 8008:80
      - 8081:8080
    volumes:
      - "./traefik.dev.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

It may be worth noting that I'm trying to customize some of the aspects of [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-docker-traefik/) FastAPI project, and to turn your attention to the *development* files and not the *production* files. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information in the comments.

Comment: take a look at `docker exec --help`

Comment: I'd recommend doing this exactly the same way you would without Docker: use the database migration system that goes with your application framework.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've just found a SO question that also discusses this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding the default container image startup command.

According to PostgreSQL official container image page, you can extend initialization adding your sh scripts (or even sql files) to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory.

See https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres.

This approach has a caveat that this script could not be executed.

Another approach is to override default container image command adding yours in bash style: `postgres; /bin/bash -c "/tmp/newtable.sh";`

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment of my question, I found another SO question that discussed this very same topic. I do, however, like your alternative method in the second part of your answer.