# Creating a postgres database for a springboot app within docker-compose.yml file

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a springboot application that conncects to a postgres database that i want to be dockerised. The below is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  db-minot-postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: minot
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - minot-network
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: minotaur:1.0
    depends_on:
      - db-minot-postgres
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB: minotaur
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db-minotaur-postgres:5432/minot
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: org.postgresql.Driver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - minot-network

networks:
  minot-network:
```

I first pulled the postgres image and then i deploy the application below so that it connects to the postgres image but i get the error

```
 minot-db-minot-postgres-1  | 2023-03-27 05:55:09.829 UTC [35] FATAL:  database "minot" does not exist
```

I dont know why it cant detect the databse as i thought when declaring the enviroment variables since the database minotaur is declared it shouldnt be a problem. Help please. How do i stop this error.

Comment: Maybe (1.) because your app tries to hit `jdbc:postgresql://db-minotaur-postgres:5432/minot` ..but it should be `db-minot-postgres`!? (2.) When "timing issues": try [better healthcheck](https://gist.github.com/MichalAdorno/747e771ddf381746c8f85d812efa5823)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have successfully connected your Postgresql inside Docker but didn't created the database as the error clearly states your database `minot` does not exist.

To create database inside docker you can follow these steps

- Make sure that the PostgreSQL Docker container is running by running the command `docker-compose up` in your project directory.
- Open a new terminal window and run the following command to enter the running PostgreSQL container:

```
    docker exec -it <container_name> bash
```

- Once you're inside the container, you can use the psql command to create the database.

```
   psql -U root -c 'CREATE DATABASE minot;'
```

This will create a new database called minot.

Exit the container by running exit.
Restart the Spring Boot application and try accessing the database again.
This time, the database should exist and the error should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres)

you can either extend postgres docker image and `COPY` your `init.sql` in it or use a bash script like this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729115/14921689)):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE my_project_development;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_project_development TO docker;
    CREATE DATABASE my_project_test;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_project_test TO docker;
EOSQL
```

compose:

```yaml
  db-minot-postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: minot
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-database.sh
    networks:
      - minot-network
```