# How to wait for database to be ready before building a new container in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mariadb_test:
    image: mariadb/server:10.5
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=10.5.0.1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

  my_service_dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_my_service
    depends_on:
      mariadb_test:
        condition: service_completed_successfully   
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=10.5.0.5
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
    tty: true
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.6

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
```

Also this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:11.6

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ARG DB_HOST
ARG DB_USER
ARG DB_PASSWORD
ENV DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
ENV DB_USER=${DB_USER}
ENV DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libmariadb3 \
    wget

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh

RUN ./wait-for-it.sh 10.5.0.5:3306 --timeout=40 -- echo "MariaDB is up"

RUN mariadb --host=${DB_HOST} --port=3306 --user=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASSWORD} -e "CREATE USER 'test_user'@'' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';"
```

When running the command `docker-compose up -d my_service_dev` I want to wait for my mariadb_test to be fully ready before starting to build my image of my_service.

I've tried 3 options so far and none of them worked:

---

**Option 1**

Trying to add this inside of **my_service**

```
depends_on:
  mariadb_test:
    condition: service_completed_successfully
```

---

**Option 2:**

Adding the atkrad/wait4x component like this:

```
  wait-for-db:
    image: atkrad/wait4x
    depends_on:
      - mariadb_test
    command: tcp mariadb_test:3306 -t 30s -i 250ms
```

And then also changing the depend_on for my_service to this:

```
depends_on:
  wait-for-db:
    condition: service_completed_successfully
```

---

**Option 3:**

Trying to run wait-for-it.sh inside my Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN ./wait-for-it.sh 10.5.0.5:3306 --timeout=40 -- echo "MariaDB is up"
```

But in this case is just going to get stuck for 40 seconds (or whatever other period of time

> wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 40 seconds for
> 10.5.0.5:3306

---

Is there any other way in which I can wait for a container to be fully ready before I can start to build my image?

Comment: You cannot interact with other containers at all from inside a Dockerfile.  (The image build does not run on the Compose network, and the Dockerfile commands won't be re-run if you delete and recreate the containers.)  If you're willing to tie the user to the database setup, [How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres) could be one option.