# How to initialize PostgreSQL database directly within a Dockerfile?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, redhat, postgresql-11

Is there a way to initialize/start/keep running a PostgreSQL DB directly from a Dockerfile? I have the following Dockerfile.

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.4.0
FROM redhat/ubi8:latest

# Install a custom modified version of PostgreSQL 11
RUN dnf install myprecious-postgresql

# Prepare for PostgreSQL
ARG psqldb=/opt/myprecious/pg/var/lib/pgsql/11
ENV PGDATA=${psqldb}/data
RUN install -d -m 0755 /var/lock/subsys
RUN install -d -m 0755 -o postgres -g postgres ${psqldb}
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql-${psqlversion} stop
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql-${psqlversion} initdb

RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql-${psqlversion} start

USER postgres
RUN <<EOF cat >> /tmp/init.sql
CREATE USER hello WITH PASSWORD 'world';
CREATE DATABASE helloworld OWNER hello;
\c helloworld
UPDATE pg_language SET lanpltrusted=true WHERE lanname='c';
GRANT ALL ON LANGUAGE c TO hello;
EOF

RUN until /opt/myprecious/pg/bin/pg_isready; do sleep 1; done;
RUN psql -f init.sql
```

But it looks like the postgresql never started (or stayed up).
[image]

Questions:

- Is there a way to keep PostgreSQL up in between steps?
- I don't want to run PostgreSQL as a separate container, I want to just run this whole thing in a box, is it possible?
- I don't necessarily need to "keep it running", I could do it at the entry point, but I'd like to initialize DB to some state, is that possible?

Comment: Each `RUN` command executes in an isolated environment. You can chain multiple shell commands together in a single `RUN` command using `;` or `&&` (`command1 && command2 && command3`), but typically you would handle database initialization at **run** time rather than **build** time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to keep PostgreSQL up in between steps?

=> nope. the idea of steps in Dockerfile is to prepare image

you need something like init.sql

```
Dockerfile

FROM library/postgres
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

In `init.sql` you can put logic to run on empty db if you run the container in first time, on next container startup if db already initialized, than run of `init.sql` will be skipped

See more details here
[How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to run PostgreSQL operations in between steps. Basically I just need to restart the db and wait for it to come up before running anything on it.

Copy the following code into a script that will be run during a step:

```
psqlversion=11
pg_initd=/etc/init.d/postgresql-$psqlversion

# We need to start postgresql again before modifying the PostgreSQL DB
# since every RUN command in Dockerfile is like a snapshot
$pg_initd start
until /opt/carillon/pg/bin/pg_isready; do sleep 1; done;
```

Anything after the above snippet, PostgreSQL will be available.