# When I build/up postgres image in docker-compose, grant command in init.sh is reset, after image shutdown immediate

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Postgres shuts down immediately when started with docker-compose.

this is my init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

echo "START INIT-DB";

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
  CREATE USER $APP_DB_USER WITH PASSWORD '$APP_DB_PWD';
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $POSTGRES_DB TO $APP_DB_USER; 
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO $APP_DB_USER;
  \connect $POSTGRES_DB $POSTGRES_USER;

EOSQL
```

this is my init.sql

```
\c test;
CREATE TABLE test (
                      id serial PRIMARY KEY,
                      test_int INT NULL,
                      test_contents varchar(50) NULL,
                      created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                      updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL,
                      deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL
);
INSERT INTO test (test_int, test_contents)
VALUES
    (12, 'abc'),
    (34, 'def');
```

After shuts down immediately, 'create user command' and 'test table' and 'inserted data' remains.

But grant command is reset!

so i cannot connect to table as APP *DB* USER!

tell me how to remain grant command, after shuts down immediately~

Comment: Does any of the information on  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres) help?

Comment: I found a solution while browsing through your link. I was completely mistaken. I thought the permissions were getting reset when the Docker image restarted, but in fact, it was working correctly.

Comment: The issue was that the 'GRANT ALL~~' command in init.sh was not granting permissions to the future tables. Since init.sh runs first and init.sql runs later, there were no permissions for the later-created 'test' table. I resolved this issue by using the '

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO $APP_DB_USER;
 ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO $APP_DB_USER;
' command to grant permissions to the future tables.
Thank you for your attention.