# Run additional commands after building a container from a Docker image downloaded from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm creating a container from the official Postgres image from Docker Hub. I just realize I want to create a new tablespace on Postrges, which requires its location directory to be present before issuing the CREATE TABLESPACE command.

I can do that by downloading the image's Dockerfile to my project directory and then modifying its content, but I don't like the idea of abandoning the use of Docker Hub. How can I run additional sh commands from docker-compose.yml during the build process just after the image build from Docker Hub is completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [README.md of the postgres](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#how-to-extend-this-image) docker image has information on how to customize the image.

You could also customize the image with a `Dockerfile` and when you run `docker-compose.yml` it builds it. (Both should be on same directory.)

Dockerfile [(ref)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

```
FROM postgres:16
RUN mkdir /data/mydirectory
```

docker-compose.yml [(ref)](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md)

```yaml
services:
  db:
    build: .
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. After further research, I found this post very useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres